# Synchronize an action on two computers connected by internet

Tags: python, time, synchronization, ping, ntp

**How is it possible to make Computer A and Computer B do an action at *exactly the same timing* in Python, such as play a sound?**

Note:

- I'm looking for a maximum timing error of 50 milliseconds
- They are not on the same local network
- In my application, the soundfile will already be in RAM, and the audio buffering time is supposed to be identical in Computer A and B

I was thinking about synchronizing the clock of both computers with an Internet time server, such as `time.nist.gov`, available here on Windows 7:

[image]

and then launch a task from Python at `14:00:00.000` (there are libraries for that) but I fear the synchronization might be good up to an error of `timeserver_computer_A_ping  + timeserver_computer_B_ping` which is maybe too much.

---

Application: I want to play a beep:

```
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.Sound('beep.wav').play()
```

at the same time on Computer A and Computer B distant of each other of 3 kilometers, and record this beep with a pocket recorder like [Zoom H2](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41d%2BD0232hL.jpg) as well as the sound of a nearby church bell. With the difference between "church bell timing - beep timing" for both Computer A and B and GPS coordinates, I would like to test if I'm able to <strike>[confirm or infirm General relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity)</strike> do basic triangulation.

Comment: Does the application have to be PyGame? If not, a simple Flask server running SocketIO will work. You can have the server send broadcast messages (an identical message to *each individual* client). I had a friend use this for a web-based music-making application and I believe his latency measurements were somewhere in the region of 10ms on a local network, so, dependent on the infrastructure between clients on separate networks, you may have usable results.

Comment: @AdamMitchell no need to use pygame, but I need something that can launch the playback of a Wav. Also both computers will be behind a rooter (A will be home router and B will be on a phone wifi hotspot)

Comment: That’s fine then; you can use a SocketIO event to trigger something like sounddevices or PyAudio to play the file.

Comment: NTP accuracy is much better than the latency between the client and server so long as the latency is symmetric (which it usually is).  It achieves this by estimating that latency; you could do the same yourself, but if you can use NTP, why not do so?

Comment: @DavisHerring I posted a question here about NTP accuracy (i.e. does it compensate the ping time from computer to time server?): https://superuser.com/questions/1327324/what-is-windowss-time-server-synchronisation-precision-and-does-it-compensate